# Rails get video or audio file time duration uploaded to AMAZON S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, video, amazon-s3, duration

In our rails app, we are uploading mp3/mp4 files directly to s3. We need to find the duration of video/audio and store it on the table. Just I tried `mp4info` gem

```
require 'taglib'
require 'mp4info'

file = "livetouch-test.mp4"
info = MP4Info.open(file)
p info.SECS
```

This provides video length, but this expecting video should be store locally. On rails app, videos/audios are available on s3 only. Anyone know how to get s3 uploaded file duration on RoR

Comment: did you get answer?

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to store the video duration and other related info in DB, when you want to upload the files, get the duration with that library you mentioned before and add the duration as meta tag when uploading the file to S3.
So, each time you want to access that file, you have access to all meta information too, you can put other meta tags such as category, etc.

For more info read the following doc on AWS
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html